# I am getting this error Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from jar

Tags: java, maven

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/appdata/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/~/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar

````
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19```
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
````

Application is built on SpringBoot using maven. I am getting this error while deploying in dev server which is a linux machine.
It is working fine in my local windows machine.
Dependencies in pom.xml is as below

```
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId> 
            <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> 
            <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId> <version>7.0.47</version> <scope>provided</scope> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Maybe linked to this bug report [BCEL-300](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BCEL-300). If this is not related to your problem please provide a bit more information. Like: Which Java version do you use locally/on the server?

Comment: @SubOptimal Java version is 1.7. The server is also having the same java version

Comment: In case the server runs with Java 7 you might have another problem as `jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar` contains class-files for Java 8. Except the file `module-info.class` which is compiled for Java 9 (the reason for the `ClassFormatException`).

Comment: You also need to check which BCEL version is used on the server, as the one installed does not yet support Java 9 class files.

Answer (score 0):

this is a tomcat bug

It is not that "Tomcat should skip or ..". It is that the underlying byte code parsing library (Apache Commons BCEL) does not know what is the meaning of entries with code "19" in a constant pool.

It knows what "18" means (CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic), bot not about "19".

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/bcel/tags/BCEL_6_0/src/main/java/org/apache/bcel/classfile/Constant.java?view=markup#l127

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/bcel/tags/BCEL_6_0/src/main/java/org/apache/bcel/Const.java?view=markup#l280

This needs

- a reference to a class file format specification (JVM specification) for the actual meaning of that code and

I expect the specs to be published here, but there is none for Java 9 yet:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

- a bug report against BCEL library.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60688

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5wX4.png)

Comment: The error is because @javaUser is using a module jar compiled by java 9+ in tomcat 7 with java <=8.

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating Tomcat did the trick, went from 8 to 9, but others said that 8.6 was enough. So I assume 赵锐斌 was right and it is indeed a Tomcat 8 bug.

Source: https://programmer.group/unable-to-process-jar-entry-module-info-class-from-jar.html